# How do I validate the contents of a textbox in c# with a button?

Tags: c#, winforms, validation

Hi a GUI that lets the user input a few different types of data. How do I go about validating the user input so that it is not blank and for some values to check if it is within a range of numbers?

Comment: What UI technology are you using? ASP.Net? WinForms? WPF?.. GTK#? We need to know...

Comment: What you need is bunch of `if ... {}` statements. If using ASP.NET you have some nice and fancy plugins using JavaScript in the client side.

Comment: I'm using C# .Net windows form

Answer (score 0):

For not blank values, you merely need to check whether `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value)` returns true or false.

For an integer range check if `value<=100 && value>=0`

For the date, check if `DateTime.TryParseExact(value, "MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out parsed)` is true or false

Answer (score 0):

You can create `IsValid` (or something like this) method inside your `Student` class (I assume that `student1` is object of class `Student`):

```
class Student
{
    // your code
    // ...
    public bool IsValid()
    {
        bool isValid = true;

        if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(FirstName))
        {
           isValid = false;
        }
        else if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(LastName))
        {
           isValid = false;
        }
        // ... rest of your validation here

        return isValid;
    }
}
```

and later:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    student1.FirstName = firstnamebox.Text;
    student1.SecondName = secondnamebox.Text;
    student1.DateofBirth = DateTime.Parse(dobtextbox.Text).Date;
    student1.Course = coursetextbox.Text;
    student1.MatriculationNumber = int.Parse(matriculationtextbox.Text);
    student1.YearMark = double.Parse(yearmarktextbox.Text);

    if(student1.IsValid())
    {
        // good
    }
    else
    {
        // bad
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey this is great, but also how would I do it for the date and range though?

Comment: @ user174357 Friend, please read some tutorials. Because after date range tomorrow you will have more conditions to validate. If you understand the basic, you can handle all these.

Comment: @user1743574 it's not that hard, e.g. for range it would be something like `if(number < 0 || number > 1024) {}` etc, for `DateTime` you can use `TryParseExact` method to parse string with datetime format of your choice.

Comment: @user1743574: Why did you try to remove this code with the comment "copyright infringement"?

Comment: @user1743574 I don't get it, why did you wanted to completly remove code from my answer with "Copyright infringement"? I wrote that code at that time, I didn't even knew how you named your `class`. You've posted some code in your original question, but you've edited it and removed code snippet from your question...? Why is that? Keep in mind that without code my answer would be useless.

Answer (score 0):

For validation in windows control, please go through following articles

[Validators for Windows Forms - ValidationProvider Control](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10093/Validators-for-Windows-Forms-ValidationProvider-Co)

[User Input Validation in Windows Forms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229603.aspx)

[Using Error Provider Control in Windows Forms and C#](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/DipalChoksi/UsingErrorProviderContolinWindowsFormsandCSharp11242005010829AM/UsingErrorProviderContolinWindowsFormsandCSharp.aspx)

For web forms.

[Validation Controls in Web Forms](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/DipalChoksi/ValidControlsWebFDPLCHK211232005034800AM/ValidControlsWebFDPLCHK2.aspx)